# Master/Detail with REST

Tags: rest, post, get, master-detail

I'm sure this topic must have been covered off before so I'm happy to be pointed to any articles etc that I may have missed while searching.

I need to implement a very simple REST API to add and retrieve records in a master/detail relationship. My two options are below:

**OPTION 1**

```
POST /master
POST /master/[id]/details
GET  /master/[id]
GET  /master/[id]/details
```

PROS

- Feels more 'RESTful'
- Can retrieve fine-grained data for performance

CONS

- A master doesn't make sense without at least one detail. How to handle atomicity? Compensating DELETE on the master if the detail fails when adding?
- Multiple calls required to retrieve the master/detail set

**OPTION 2**

```
POST /master_and_details
GET  /master_and_details/[master id]
```

PROS

- Easy to manage atomicity

CONS

- More complex structure to manage
- GETs must return entire structure (not always efficient)
- Doesn't feel very 'RESTful'

Thanks,
John

Comment: REST more or less dictates option 1, option 2 is just a plain old http api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST more or less dictates option 1, option 2 is just a plain old http api.

Your statement that a master makes no sense without at least one detail is probably wrong. You have no idea how your api will be used in the future by clever developers. You can guess, but you don't really know.

If you really need the compound solution yourself you could always add an interface at a higher level that calls onto the two separate interfaces and returns a compound object.

Option 1 allows the possibility of a microservice implementation -- or at least, a separation of concerns into two separable objects. Option 2 alone would not.

Comment: Thanks. Understand that devs may use the resources independently at some point in the future. This structure leaves the door open for this but I still need to ensure atomicity for this particular usage. I can write a wrapper as you said to orchestrate the mast and detail POSTs but will need to compensate if they fail meaning a DELETE service will be required. Would you suggest a DELETE master and cascade, or separate DELETE services would be best? Again the separate services feels more 'RESTful' but would require more work to compensate if multiple details records must be rolled back. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, to do this properly you need to consider more than whether the api is restful or not. Have you read Implementing Domain Driven Design, by Vaughn Vernon? http://www.amazon.co.uk/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577

Answer (score 2):

At least for sake of argument, and risking my meager reputation, I'll venture a third approach.

You'd have two resources: master and detail.  (not "details", unless you want to go totally plural, in which case you'd have "masters" and "details").  The representation of master would include the collection of details, or (better) link relations to the details.  Consider https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573 for that link relation.

Therefore GET of master includes (directly or indirectly via relation) the collection of detail.  POST/PUT of master can also POST/PUT detail members by their presence in the form data.

Any detail can also be GET/PUT/POSTED independently of the master. Here, the design depends somewhat on whether a detail has its own primary key, vs. using a composite key with its master.  If it has its own primary key then you could have:

```
GET /detail/{detailKey}  - gets specific detail
POST /detail  - creates new detail
GET /master/{masterkey}/detail  -- gets all details for master
GET /master{masterkey}/detail/{detailkey} -- get specific detail
```

obviously, on the POST, the data must include the key of the master.

You see that there is more than one URI for getting a detail. I don't think that that's wrong, but it does introduce some ambiguity:  if detailKey is not actually a child of masterKey, do you 404? I'd say yes.

if the detail uses a composite key, then it can't be  GETed independently of the master, so the first form shown above could not be supported. Also, {detailKey}, as used in the last example above, would be the identifier of the detail item within the master (typically a sequence number).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with **Option 1**, as **Option 2** has nothing to do with REST. But that does not mean, that you need to use multiple querys to get `Master` + `Detail`.
As the `Detail` belongs to the `Master` (and so it is part of it), in my opinion it is absolutely ok to return `Master` and the `Detail`, when querying the `Master`.
You might also consider using a parameters to control whether to send the `Detail` or not.
So instead of executing `GET /master/1` you could use `GET /master/1?detail=true`.
For `POST` and `PUT` more or less the same would work. Just instead of having the query parameter, you have a "section" in your body regarding the `Detail`.
An Example using JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "master",
    "detail": [
      {
        "name": "detail1"
      },
      {
        "name": "detail2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

A `POST` with this data could create a `Master` with the `name` "master" and 2 `Detail`s for this `Master`.

As @ElroyFlynn stated before, the `Detail`s could also be accessible without the `Master`, if this makes sence.
Think about a forum with `Thread`s and `Post`s. Usualy a `Thread` is the `Master` and every `Post` is a `Detail`. But if you want to search all `Post`s of the last hour, you definitely want to query the posts directly (the query could be something like `GET /post?max_age=1h`).

Also I don't agree, that a `Master` without `Detail` does not make sence. There might be cases, where it doesn't, but in the case of the forum, a `Thread` on it's own makes sence.
For the `atomicity`:
It depends on the case: If you delete a `User` you usually keep his `Post`s (even here on StackOverflow). If you instead delete a `Thread`, I guess, you can delete the `Post`s to.